# Eigen C++; In-place matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, eigen3

Using the **Eigen** C++ Matrix library, how can one efficiently 
multiply an *n x n* matrix *A* with a *n x m* matrix *B* 
and store the result in *A*? That is, how can I avoid 
generating a temporary *n x m* matrix and instead store
the result directly in *B*?

For applications where *m* is very much larger (e.g. 100000) 
than *n* (e.g. 3), this definitely makes sense since it avoids 
the application of very a large array.

The following code, I cannot get to work:

```
     B.noalias() = A * B;
```

I would think, that what would have to happen internally is 
the following. Each column of *B* should be treated separately. 
The column under consideration `column_i` must be copied to a backup 
column `column_tmp`. Then,

```
     B(row_i, column_i) = A.row(row_i) * column_tmp; // dot-product
```

for all `column_i` = *0 to m*. Is there a way in **Eigen** to do this
efficiently and profit from its optimizations?

Comment: I think you mean "store the result in B"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most *explicit* way of telling Eigen that you want the product to happen "in place" could be:

```
B.transpose() *= A.transpose();
// or B.applyOnTheLeft(A);
```

that said, there's no guarantee this won't incur in *any* temporary, you'll have to trust internal Eigen cost logic for that (Eigen designers probably know better :) ... or check it yourself via a debugger, after proper profiling suggested this to be a *real* problem and not just premature optimization).

On my Eigen copy (3.2.7), the above invokes `MatrixBase::applyThisOnTheRight` directly on the `Transpose` expression, that in turn sadly reduces to `B=A*B` internally; the same happens as of `applyOnTheLeft`, so you're out of luck in this case.

If you really need to avoid *any* nxm temporary, you can perform the product manually vector-wise, something like:

```
for(auto i=0;i<B.cols();++i)
    B.col(i) = A * B.col(i);
```

this will consume much less extra memory assuming `B.rows()`<<`B.cols()`, 
but you may miss some important optimizations here; indeed, I guess having a temporary could still give the best trade-off here.

Comment: What is the purpose of the '.transpose()' call in the '*=' assignment.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer to make it equivalent to `B = A*B` (take the transposed of both sides)

Comment: Sorry I do not get it. What is the difference between the two operations `B *= A` and  `B.transpose() *= A.transpose()`?

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer `B*=A` is `B=B*A` whereas we want `B=A*B`, that is `B^T=(A*B)^T` that is `B^T=B^T*A^T` that is `B^T*=A^T`

Answer (score 2):

Yes with a 3x3 times 3xHuge your column-by-column evaluation would indeed make sense, but not in the general case. For instance, if n=m=1000, then the column-by-column evaluation would be orders of magnitude slower than the current Eigen logic.

If you write:

```
B.noalias() = A * B;
```

Eigen will follow a col-by-col evaluation (because A is small at compile-time), but the result will be wrong because B does alias, basically it will generate:

```
for j = 0..m-1
  B.col(j).noalias() = A * B.col(j);
```

To solve this issue elegantly we would need a way to say that only different columns do not alias... The proposed:

```
B.transpose() *= A.transpose();
```

is indeed an option let Eigen knows at compile time this kind of information, though having to transpose both sides is a bit cumbersome. And the proper evaluation logic still needs to be implemented on Eigen's side. Currently this information is not exploited.

Comment: another, more explicit way (that currently Eigen does not recognize as a valid expression) could be `B.tranpose().rowwise() *= A.transpose()`, this would make evident the intent of the caller ... (at the cost of worse optimization in the general case)

Comment: another thing I'd like to see in some future Eigen version, is a way to give 'optimization hints' via expressions, something like `B.transpose() *= smallish(A).transpose();` ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes It should be possible to specialize `applyThisOnTheLeft` and `applyThisOnTheRight` for small at compile-time matrices to evaluate column-by-column or row-by-row in place (it needs someone with time to implement this, though)

Answer (score 1):

Your example of `B.noalias() = A * B;` does not match "store the result in A". All you need for *that* is `A *= B;`. If you instead *do* intend to overwrite `B`, then you are *lying* with [`.noalias()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a2c1085de7645f23f240876388457da0b)

Comment: Will `A *= B` operate in-place, as opposed to `A = A * B`, which apparently does not?