# Multiply one matrix "in-place" by another square matrix for memory efficiency?

Tags: c++, c, math

If I have a square matrix A of dimension M x M and a matrix B of dimension M x N, they are compatiable to be multiplied and the resulting matrix will have the same dimensions as matrix B.

I've found myself in a situation where these matrices are quite large and of dynamic size. This means that I have to make big memory allocations for 3 matrices to calculate the answer A * B, when I only really care about the answer and don't mind "losing" either A or B after the calculation.

Is there any clever trick I could use to multiply A * B "in-place" so that the resulting product is stored directly in B (as it has the same dimensions as the answer), thus saving memory allocations? Performance is critical in the function I am writing.

Comment: Woops... Made a typoe. Correcting now @ChrisDodd

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450809/is-there-an-algorithm-to-multiply-square-matrices-in-place

Comment: If B is non-square the result will have the same dimensions as the transpose of B.

Comment: Are you open to library suggestions? Eigen is relatively lightweight, and does a good job handling these sorts of things-- [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296384/eigen-c-in-place-matrix-multiplication). I've used it for very memory and cpu intensive in-place matrix math, and was very satisfied.

Comment: You should look into [cache blocking](https://www.google.com/search?q=cache+blocking+matrix+multiplication) -- the algorithms for fitting matrix mulitplication into the cache are the same as you need for fitting in limited memory.

Comment: Unfortunately using a library would not work in my environment, Eigen looks cool though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if you store a copy of a single column of B before calculating the same column of the result into this column of B. You can reuse this column-sized helper array for the calculation of every column of the result. This way you only need to store A (MxM), B (MxN), and an array of size M.

Here is a little C-like pseudocode to demonstrate what I mean:

```c
int A[3][3] = {{11, 12, 13}, {21, 22, 23}, {31, 32, 33}};
int B[3][5] = {{11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}, {31, 32, 33, 34, 35}};
int C[3]; // Helper array
for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
    // Copy the j-th column of B into the helper array 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        C[i] = B[i][j];
    }
    // Calculate the j-th column of the result in-place (in B) using the helper array
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        B[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
            B[i][j] += A[i][k] * C[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that really is the only solution due to the nature of matrix multiplication. Appreciate it!